# Run a Python code that exceutes a shell script and enters a password

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi

I've programmed a motion detector on my Raspberry Pi. I also programmed a shell script, that takes a picture and sends the picture to a another server. I gave both servers authorized keys, so I don't have to enter a password if I execute the script. This works fine but if I run my Python script it continuously asks for the Password to the other server. **This is my code:**

```
import os as path
path.system(" sudo -S /home/pi/webcam.sh")
```

Security is not important so I can write the password in the Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try running your Python code as administrator. Since it asks for a password within the Python script, I would assume that your server sees the script as a non-admin.